# Realm JS Create objects with primitive data type list

Tags: reactjs, realm, realm-list

I am unable to create a list of only string objects

This is how my model looks like

```
class ProductSummary extends Realm.Object {}
ProductSummary.schema = {
name: 'ProductSummary',
properties: {
productId:'string',
name:'string',
description:'string',
rating:'int',
comments:'int',
categories:{type:'list',objectType:'string'},
images:{type:'list',objectType:'string'},
price:{type:'Price'}
 }
};
```

This is how the response I get from the api

```
"productSummary": { "links": [], "productId": "PRD_1ola611nd0t", "name": "Sample", "description": "<p>Sample<br></p>", "categories": [ "CAT_1rua60fnd0u" ], "rating": 0, "comments": 0, "tags": [], "image": "http://test.testsite.com/testProject/app-images/189_66164247/189_42527954.jpeg", "price": { "lowest": 100, "highest": 100 } }
```

I get the following error

`Target Type 'string' doesn't Exists for property 'categories'`

Am I creating the Category field in the wrong way.

Comment: This also has a GitHub issue now: https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/545

Comment: yep I'll add an answer to this post, in a while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a limitation with realm js for react native, a work around is to wrap the list of strings as list of objects (as key value pairs) before doing the db transaction, more info and the status of the issue is tracked in this [github issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/545)

Answer (score 1):

Now we can create a list of only string object or any primitive value type.

e.g.

```
class VarietyModel {}

VarietyModel.schema = {
  name: 'Variety',
  primaryKey: 'varietyId',
  properties: {
    varietyId: 'int',
    varietyName: 'string',
    products: { type: 'string?[]', default: [] }, // products will array of strings ['product1','product2'..]
  },
};
export default VarietyModel;
```

Reff:

[Realm Types](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/react-native/data-types/field-types/)

[Realm List Properties](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm-legacy/docs/javascript/latest.html)